# Inconsistency in TypeScript function overload

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading, typescript-typings

Consider this example:

```
export function fn(arg: string): void;
export function fn(arg: number): void;
export function fn(arg: any) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

So, `fn` can be called either with a string, or a number.

```
fn('hello!');
fn(42);
```

So far, so good.
But then `fn` is executed in a different place:

```
function fn2(arg2: string | number) {
    fn(arg2);
}
```

In this case TypeScript complains:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(arg: string):
> void', gave the following error.

> ```
> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(arg: number): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2769)
> ```

> index.tsx(3, 17): The call would have succeeded against this
> implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not
> externally visible.

Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You can add another overload

```js
export function fn(arg: string): void;
export function fn(arg: number): void;
export function fn(arg: any): void;
export function fn(arg: any) {
    console.log(arg);
}

fn('hello!');
fn(42);

function fn2(arg2: string | number) {
    fn(arg2);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWJQCgEMoBzALjgGcYpMUSBKCgNwkwBMBuAKFElkSoM2XAgLFycFEgC2AI2BQmcVhx59o8ZOiw48RUhUIoAnstVde4TYJ0j9Eo6YZwA3tzie4aHJQgAbYAA6fwgSA0YeAF9ubjF8AHIAC2B-UIBCBIYeeIAWACZs2O1hPTF8iPyKalp6OAAfKVkFJTcPL3iJQuigA)

Comment: This fixed it for me but I have no idea why. Can you explain why this fixed it for me?

Comment: @ElliotLabsLLC Because the new overload signature accepts an argument of type any.

Comment: So the new `arg:any` param mirrors the non overload function params which aren't counted for the sake of Transpiler function param construction?

Comment: It just covers `any`thing including union types which in this case would be `arg2: string | number`

Comment: got ya, so why couldn't the base function handle it? Why does it have to be an additional overload?

Comment: Because there was no overload declared for the union and as far as typescript cares, `number` or `string` can be assigned to `number | string` but not vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Overloads aren't the same as Union Types. Overloads define 'separate' functions  while unions allow you to put different types as arguments.

```
// fails
function fn2(arg2: string | number) {

    fn(arg2); // uses the union type
}

// works 
function fn3(arg2: string | number) {
    
    if(typeof arg2  === 'string') {
        return fn(arg2); // uses string
    }
    
    return fn(arg2); // uses number
}
```

This means `fn2` searches for a function declaration that has an argument of type `string|number` while `fn3` searches for either a function with type `string` or a function with type `number` as its first argument.

You should not use `any` if you exactly know, which type you want as a function parameter.

See the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for Union Types